# Fortify AWB Out of Memory Opening FPR File

Tags: jvm, fortify

When opening an FPR file, Fortify AWB is running out of memory. The java process climbs to about 1150mb before it plateaus and then the error message is displayed. I have tried setting AWB_VM_OPTS and SCA_VM_OPTS to -Xmx4G but the amount of memory allocated doesn't seem to change.

What can be done to increase the amount of allocated memory?

Comment: Did you try it after a fresh reboot? I've seen that help. Also, do you know if you can audit the file in the SSC? I guess it's possible that the FPR is corrupt and checking in the SSC should let you know that.

Comment: I do not have Fortify SSC. To scan the file I had to spend some time reading the documentation and increase the scan Xmx to 10G. The project is very large. I am honestly confused as to why these settings are not enabled by default as I don't see any typical use case where people would want Fortify to crash with out of memory errors and be forced to navigate through documentation.

Comment: I agree. Fortify had great analysis but a terrible user experience. Glad you got it working

Comment: Sorry, I mean that I had to increase the memory to scan the file, not to open the FPR scan results with the AWB. That is where I am currently experiencing issues. I'm glad to see I am not the only one who is frustrated with this software.

Answer (score 2):

When running SCA, the amount of physical RAM required is dependent on a number of factors. These factors, which include the size and complexity of the source file, make it impossible to quantify and provide guidance -- each situation is unique. If you do encounter a low memory error, increasing the amount of memory available to SCA may resolve the problem.

By default, SCA uses up to 600 MB of memory. If this is not sufficient to analyze a particular code base, you might have to provide more memory in the scan phase. This can be done by passing the -Xmx option to the sourceanalyzer command.

For example, to make 1000 MB available to SCA, include the option -Xmx1000M.
You can also use the SCA_VM_OPTS environment variable to set the memory allocation.

Do not allocate more memory for SCA than the machine has available, because this will degrade performance. As a guideline, assuming that no other memory-intensive processes are running, do not allocate more than 2/3 of the available physical memory.

If memory problems persist, set the Windows paging file to a fixed amount of about 1.5 times the amount of hardware RAM on your computer. Go to System Properties, Select Performance Settings. Then under the Advanced tab, note the “Total paging file size for all drives.”  That amount should match the amount of hardware RAM in your computer. Push the Change button; un-check “Automatically manage paging file size for all drives.” Select the “Custom size” option and enter a value 1.5 times the size of RAM in your computer as the “Initial size” and the “Maximum size.”

Answer (score 2):

We got around this problem by opening the file `C:\Program Files\Fortify\Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_20.1.0\bin\auditworkbench.cmd` and adding this to the end of the "`call`" command:

```
-Xmx10G -64
```

So, afterwards, our line looks like this:

```
call "%~dp0\..\Core\private-bin\awb\productlaunch.cmd" -showSplash platform:/base/plugins/com.fortify.awb.app/splash.bmp -application com.fortify.awb.app.Main -product com.fortify.awb.app.MainProduct "-Dosgi.splashPath=platform:/base/plugins/com.fortify.awb.app" %* -Xmx10G -64
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for this is to not edit environmental variables. If you have done this delete it and follow these steps. NOTE This is for SCA 20.2+

1. Navigate to: C:\Forityscainstallpath\Core\private-bin\awb
2. Open productlaunch.cmd in a text editor such as Notepad++
3. Scroll to the bottom which is line 56 for me and update the following line. Where I have Xmx12g input your preference. NOTE: It took me a few tries to get it right.

start "Fortify" /B /MIN "%FORTIFY_CORE%\private-bin\awb\eclipse\eclipse.exe" -vm "%JAVA_CMD%" -startup "%FORTIFY_CORE%\lib\awb-startup-20.2.2.0003.jar" -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 %USER_OPTS% %AWB_ARGS% -vmargs -Xmx12G -XX:-UseCompressedOops %AWB_VM_OPTS% %USER_VM_OPTS% -Dcom.fortify.InstallRoot="%FORTIFY_HOME%" >NUL

4. Save the file
5. Close and retry
6. Increase memory until it works, but do not exceed available memory.

Answer (score 0):

After confirming that AWB_VM_OPTS was the value I wanted to change, I decided to create a short script that set the value and then called the AWB bat file that starts the application. Previously I was setting AWB_VM_OPTS manually in the command prompt. I set the value to 4096M instead of 4G and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

C:\Program Files\Fortify\Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_18.20\Core\config\fortify.properties
com.fortify.model.ExecMemorySetting=5460M

C:\Program Files\Fortify\Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_18.20\bin\auditworkbench.cmd
set SCA_VM_OPTS=-Xmx5460M

Comment: I'd suggest adding an explaination to those lines